# Convert int element to char and then to string Kotlin error?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, type-conversion

I'm trying to pass an int element to a char and then to a string, but isn't working (The string shows nothing). Here's the part of the code I'm having trouble with. Any help is really useful, thank you

```
private fun setFicha(view: ImageView, posicionFila: Int, posicionColumna: Int){
       val texto = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texto)
       if(tablero[posicionFila][posicionColumna] == '-') {
           total++
           tablero[posicionFila][posicionColumna] = total.toChar()
           texto.text = tablero[posicionFila][posicionColumna].toString()
       }
       checkGameOver()
   }
```

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem. What you want to store in `tablero`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert `Char` back to `Int` use `code` property:

```kotlin
49.toChar() // => '1' (Char)
```

```kotlin
49.toChar().code // => 49 (Int)
```

```kotlin
49.toChar().code.toString() // => "49" (String)
```

`Char` type in Kotlin represents a 16-bit Unicode character. Code 49 corresponds to character '1'.

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much :)